# Aggregation on time interval

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say document has

```
{startDate,endDate}
```

fields among other fields.

And now we want to create range aggregation based on these fields.
So document must appear in each bucket that overlaps with start-end interval.

I found that aggregation is not supported yet on `Range Fields` => https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/34644

As a workaround => I can use script and since I know size(time interval) of buckets I could generate array of values between start-end dates

```
aggregation_field : [startDate + bucketSize, startDate + bucketSize * 2, .... endDate]
```

But in some cases this array could be huge.

Are there other workarounds ?
Thanks !

Comment: Not sure if you considered histogram aggregation - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html

Comment: histogram aggregation uses only one field for aggregation. In my case we have interval startDate-endDate

Comment: @resorcher may I know what's your intention here, `enddate-startdate` would be showing you difference of let's say 1 day or 2 days, would you like to have aggregation based on the difference of the days irrespective of it occurring in any month or year?